# How to get the whole html from webbrowser.document

Tags: html, vb.net

If dw1() return webbrowser.document I know I can do:

```
dw1.body.outerhtml
```

to get the outerhtml of the body. That's it, body, header, etc.

What about if I want to get the html of the whole document?

Comment: WebBrowser1.DocumentText is not a good way to ensure you get ALL HTML from within WebBrowser1.Document.  This is because there are multiple ways to add to and alter the live HTML data that does NOT update WebBrowser1.DocumentText.  To ensure you get every single bit of code in your live data, target the most outer tags in your code and grab everything in-between that. That's usually the HTML tags. Use this instead - WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML").Item(0).OuterHtml. I already answered this in another question so my answer here got deleted but I wanted to make sure YOU got it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the webbrowser control, you can use the `DocumentText` property:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    MessageBox.Show(WebBrowser1.DocumentText) 
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't get everything.  If you made InnerHTML changes (for example) after the DocumentText was created you only get the original DocumentText.  OuterHTML grabs the changes but you only get what's inside the BODY tag.