# Get full HTML code from WebBrowser control

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control in a form in which I load an HTML page from the application's resources.

The HTML page serves as a template and, through code, I'm going to insert into it some strings and other data via the function:

`WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById function ("TD101"). InnerText = "OK"`

I would like to access the content of entire page, but using the `WebBrowser.DocumentText` function only gives the template HTML with no strings inserted by me.

Instead, using the `WebBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml` function I can see the page with the correct values entered but since it does not return the head of the page, I lose all the CSS code.

Is there any function that will let me access ALL of the HTML contents of the control?

Thank you all.

EDIT: As i told in my question the `WebBrowser.DocumentText` return only the template HTML code without my update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the whole html from webbrowser.document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872883/how-to-get-the-whole-html-from-webbrowser-document)

Comment: As i told in my question the `WebBrowser.DocumentText` return only the template HTML code without my update.

Answer (score 0):

Below my tests with excel VBA for getting text from a WebBrowser form

Create an userform, name: WebForm
with two buttons "TEST_1" and "TEST_2"
and a WebBrowser control, name: WebBrowser1

Code in standard module:

```
Sub Macro_1()
MsgBox "Macro 1 test"
End Sub
Sub Macro_2()
MsgBox "Macro 2 test"
End Sub
Sub UserForm_WebForm_Show()
On Error GoTo ExceptionHandling

Dim frm As WebForm
Set frm = New WebForm
With frm
    .Show vbModeless
End With
'Unload frm
'Set frm = Nothing

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
ExceptionHandling:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.description
    Resume CleanUp
    Resume 'for debugging
End Sub
```

Code in WebForm module:

```
Private WithEvents ie As WebBrowser
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
On Error GoTo ExceptionHandling

Set ie = Me.WebBrowser1
ie.Navigate2 "about:blank"
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
ie.Document.body.Scroll = "no"

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
ExceptionHandling:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.description
    Resume CleanUp
    Resume 'for debugging
End Sub
Private Sub Salir_Click()
'Unload Me
Me.Hide
End Sub
Private Sub TEST_1_Click()

Dim sHTML As String
sHTML = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" & vbCrLf & _
    "<html>" & vbCrLf & _
    "<head>" & vbCrLf & _
    "<meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=edge"" />" & vbCrLf & _
    "<title>Test</title>" & vbCrLf & _
    "</head>" & vbCrLf & _
    "<body>" & vbCrLf & _
    "<b>Text 1</b>" & vbCrLf & _
    "</body>" & vbCrLf & _
    "</html>"

With ie.Document
    ie.Document.Open
    .Write sHTML
    ie.Document.Close
End With
ie.Refresh

''ie.Navigate2 ActiveWorkBook.Path & "\myFile.htm"
'ie.Navigate2 "https://..."
Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
Private Sub TEST_2_Click()

Dim sHTML As String
sHTML = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>"
sHTML = sHTML & "<html>"
sHTML = sHTML & "<head>"
sHTML = sHTML & "<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />"
sHTML = sHTML & "<title>Test</title>"
sHTML = sHTML & "</head>"
sHTML = sHTML & "<body>"

sHTML = sHTML & "<table role='presentation' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' align='center' style='margin: auto;'>" _
    & "<tr><td style='border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;' class='button-td'><a href='Macro_1' cancel='true' style='background: #666666; border: 15px solid #666666; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;' class='button-a'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='color:#ffffff'>Macro 1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td>" _
    & "<td>&nbsp;</td>" _
    & "<td style='border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;' class='button-td'><a href='Macro_2' cancel='true' style='background: #666666; border: 15px solid #666666; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;' class='button-a'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='color:#ffffff'>Macro 2</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td>" _
    & "<td>&nbsp;</td>" _
    & "<td style='border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;' class='button-td'><a href='Macro_3' cancel='true' style='background: #666666; border: 15px solid #666666; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;' class='button-a'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='color:#ffffff'>Macro 3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td>" _
    & "</tr></table>"

'https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/197979-ie-embedded-capturing-events/?do=findComment&comment=1427391
sHTML = sHTML & "<form>"
sHTML = sHTML & "First name: <input id='firstname' type='text' name='firstname'/><br/>"
sHTML = sHTML & "Last name: <input id='lastname' type='text' name='lastname'/><br/>"
sHTML = sHTML & "Password: <input id='password' type='password' name='pwd'/><br><br/>"
sHTML = sHTML & "<input type='radio' id='male' name='sex' value='male'/>Male<br/>"
sHTML = sHTML & "<input type='radio' id='female' name='sex' value='female'/>Female<br/><br/>"
sHTML = sHTML & "<input type='checkbox' id='bike' name='vehicle' value='Bike'/>I have a bike<br/>"
sHTML = sHTML & "<input type='checkbox' id='car' name='vehicle' value='Car'/>I have a car <br/><br/>"
sHTML = sHTML & "</form>"

sHTML = sHTML & "</body>"
sHTML = sHTML & "</html>"

With ie.Document
    ie.Document.Open
    .Write sHTML
    ie.Document.Close
End With
ie.Refresh

Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        this.IsCancelled = True
        Me.Hide
        Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.ToolBar(""Ribbon"", True)"
        'Only in Excel 2010-2016 you can use this to hide the view of only the Ribbon
        'CommandBars.ExecuteMso "MinimizeRibbon"
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ie_BeforeNavigate2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant, Flags As Variant, TargetFrameName As Variant, PostData As Variant, Headers As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
If URL = "about:blank" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    'MsgBox "'Command': " & Mid(URL, 7)
    If Not Right(URL, 1) = 3 Then
        Run Mid(URL, 7)
    Else
        Call Macro_3
    End If
    'Set the cancel boolean to true so that the webbrowser control isn't trying to navigate.
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
Sub Macro_3()

On Error Resume Next

'OK
Debug.Print "--- Macro_3: Test 1"
Debug.Print ie.Document.GetElementsByName("firstname").Item(0).Value
Debug.Print ie.Document.getElementById("firstname").Value


'OK
Debug.Print "--- Macro_3: Test 2"
Dim inputfield As Object
Set inputfield = ie.Document.getElementById("firstname")
''inputfield.Value = "ZZZ"
''inputfield.InnerText = "hello world"
'inputfield.SetAttribute "value", "your text to search"
'ie.Document.All.Item("firstname").Value = "hello world"
Debug.Print inputfield.Value

'OK
Debug.Print "--- Macro_3: Test 3"
Dim textElement As Object
Set textElement = ie.Document.GetElementsByName("firstname")
For Each HtmlElement In textElement
    Debug.Print HtmlElement.Name, HtmlElement.Value
Next HtmlElement

'OK
Debug.Print "--- Macro_3: Test 4"
Dim HTMLdoc As Object
Set HTMLdoc = ie.Document
For Each HtmlElement In HTMLdoc.All
    If HtmlElement.GetAttribute("type") = "text" Then
        Debug.Print HtmlElement.Value
    End If
Next HtmlElement

'Not OK but all returning something
'Debug.Print "--- Macro_3: Fails to return changed text"
'Debug.Print ie.Document.All(0).InnerHTML
'Debug.Print ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML").Item(0).InnerHTML
'Debug.Print ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HTML").Item(0).OuterHtml
End Sub
```

This is wat i get in immediate window:

```
--- Macro_3: Test 1
MyFirstName
MyFirstName
--- Macro_3: Test 2
MyFirstName
--- Macro_3: Test 3
firstname     MyFirstName
--- Macro_3: Test 4
MyFirstName
```

[Here the excel file (see end of post)](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/197979-ie-embedded-capturing-events/?do=findComment&comment=1427391)